# How to rename the temp file to original text file?

Tags: java, text-files

Hello my code basically **delete the empty lines from txt file**, but i want at the end temp file take the originals name.

```
    String inputFileName = "src/inware/users.txt";
    String outputFileName = "src/inware/usersT.txt";

    try (BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName));
         PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outputFileName))) {
        String lineOfText;
        while ((lineOfText = inputFile.readLine()) != null) {
            lineOfText = lineOfText.trim();
            if (!lineOfText.isEmpty()) {
                outputFile.println(lineOfText);
            }
        }
        inputFile.close();
        outputFile.close();

        inputFile.delete();
        outputFile.renameTo(inputFile);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ManageStudentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I try

```
        inputFile.delete();
        outputFile.renameTo(inputFile);
```

But is not working... Any solution??

Comment: *Where* did you add those two lines of code?

Comment: Try using [`Files.delete(Path path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-) and [`Files.move(Path source, Path target)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) instead, since they will throw exception if operation fails, explaining why, rather than just return an uninformative `false` value like the old [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) methods do.

Comment: @Andreas i add them after  `inputFile.close();outputFile.close();` .Do you mean like that `Files.delete("src/inware/users.txt");Files.move("src/inware/users.txt","src/inware/usersT.txt");` .Still not working im getting error

Comment: Did you look at the links Andreas provided?  The arguments must be Path objects, not Strings.

Comment: First, you can't do `inputFile.delete()` since `inputFile` is a `BufferedReader`, not a `File`. --- Instead of `new File(inputFileName).delete()`, you use `Files.delete(Paths.get(inputFileName))`.

Comment: *FYI:* Since you're using try-with-resources, don't close the streams yourself. Move the delete and rename outside the `try` block.

Comment: can't detect anything related to javafx so removed the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found better solution that fix my problem:

```
    Path p = Paths.get("src", "inware", "users.txt");
    try {
        Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(p.getParent(), "usersTemp", ".txt");
        try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(p);
             PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(tempFile))) {
            for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null;) {
                line = line.trim();
                if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                    out.println(line);
                }
            }
        }
        Files.copy(tempFile, p, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        Files.delete(tempFile);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ManageStudentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the new File NIO.2 API instead of the old antiquated File I/O API.

This means that you should use [`Files.delete(Path path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-) and [`Files.move(Path source, Path target)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) instead, since they will throw exception if operation fails, explaining **why**, rather than just return an uninformative `false` value like the old [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) methods do.

Also, since you're using *try-with-resources*, don't close the streams yourself. Close the `try` block at the time you want the resources closed.

Change the code to:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
```

```
Path inputFile = Paths.get("src/inware/users.txt");
Path outputFile = Paths.get("src/inware/usersT.txt");
try {
    try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(inputFile);
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFile))) {
        for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
            line = line.trim();
            if (! line.isEmpty())
                out.println(line);
        }
    }
    Files.delete(inputFile);
    Files.move(inputFile, outputFile);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ManageStudentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

If the delete+rename fails, you'll now know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
File tempFile = new File(tempDir, name + "." + imageType);
```